# Target class [StudentController] does not exist. http://localhost:8000/student

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am building a module called Student in Laravel.

I use the `routes.php` file inside the Student folder to write routes related to student module..

When I use just

```
Route::get('/main', function () { return view('welcome'); });
```

program working fine without error.

But when I am using

```
Route::get('/student', 'StudentController@student');
```

there is an error: `Target class [StudentController] does not exist.`

Comment: do you create controller StudentController?

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Student' not found
http://localhost:8000/

Comment: you should check your path of your controller Student.